# python GUI automation on different desktop

Tags: python, automation, virtual-machine, ui-automation, pyautogui

I am opening this thread because I would like to know more about GUI tasks automation. I have been told that some Python module such as PyAutoGUI or Automa can be used to litterally allow a Python scrip to take the control of my computer mousse and keybord in the aim to do some taks.

I found this really interesting and I would like to know if there is way to make this in parallel, in a way to allow the user to use their machine at the same time.

For example, I know that on Windows, it is possible to create a secondary desktop and put some programs windows on it. Therefore I was wondering if it could be possible to put the tasks to automatize on this secondary windows then run the GUI tasks automation python script. That would however imply to create secondary mousse and keybord to avoid any interaction intereferences between the user and the automation script.

There is also the possiblity to use virtual machines, but that would imply to install all the required programs that I want to automatize on this virtual machine, and I would rather like to avoid this. But I do not know, maybe there is way to allow a virtual machines to access to all real machine programs ?

I am opened to any suggestion, this topic is very new to me.
Thanks in advance for your help